# node server calling api twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am running an application built in MEAN. The node server is calling the api twice. I tried using console.log(req.url). It returns the same url "/profile" both times. 
Angular.js code

```js
app.controller('profile',['$scope','$http','$state', function($scope,$http, $state){
 $http({
  url:'/profile',
  method:'post',
  data:{
   
  }
 }).success(function(data){
  if(data){
   
   console.log("from profile controller" + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  });
 
}]);
```

In app.js I m calling /profile api as
app.get('/profile', queries.profile)

queries.js code

```js
exports.profile = function(req, res){   
 mongo.connect(mongoURL, function(){
  console.log(req.url);
  var coll= mongo.collection('users');
   coll.findOne({"email": req.session.email}, function(err, user){
   if(user){
    console.log("this is result " + JSON.stringify(user));
    res.send(user);
   }
   else{
    console.log("error");
   }
  });
  });
};
```

Plaese tell me where i m going wrong.

Comment: In your angular code you are using the method `POST`, but in your app.js code you are saying that profile is assigned to `app.get()`... it would be good to see the app.js code as well.

Comment: Possibly a preflight request(OPTIONS method) initiated before the actual one. You could inspect the request method in devtool.

Comment: my bad.. I am actually using app.post in my app.js .. app.post('/profile', queries.profile);